# Gradle DSL method not found: 'implemantation()'

Tags: java, android, gradle, syntax-error, mobile-application

the problem is below

> Gradle DSL method not found: 'implemantation()'
>
> Possible causes:
>
> Your project may be using a version of the Android Gradle plug-in that does not contain the method (e.g. 'testCompile' was added in 1.1.0).
>
> Upgrade plugin to version 8.2.0 and sync project
>
> Open Gradle wrapper file
>
> Apply Gradle plugin

build.gradle(Modue:app)

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id('androidx.navigation.safeargs')
    id('dagger.hilt.android.plugin')
}

android {
    namespace 'com.mucahit.kisileruygulamasi'
    compileSdk 34

    buildFeatures{
        viewBinding = true;
    }

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.mucahit.kisileruygulamasi"
        minSdk 24
        targetSdk 34
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}

dependencies {
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.uiautomator:uiautomator:2.2.0'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.10.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment:2.7.5'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-ui:2.7.5'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel:2.5.1'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.1'

    implemantation("com.google.dagger:hilt-android:2.44")
    annotationProcessor("com.google.dagger:hilt-android-compiler:2.44")
}
```

build.gradle(Project)

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
buildscript {
    dependencies {
        classpath("androidx.navigation:navigation-safe-args-gradle-plugin:2.5.3")
        classpath("com.google.dagger:hilt-android-gradle-plugin:2.44")

    }
}
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application' version '8.2.0' apply false
    id 'com.android.library' version '8.2.0' apply false
}
```

I think there is a mistake in build.gradle(Module.app)->

`plugins {     ...     id('dagger.hilt.android.plugin') }`

```
dependencies {
    ...

    implemantation("com.google.dagger:hilt-android:2.44")
    annotationProcessor("com.google.dagger:hilt-android-compiler:2.44")
}
```

I wanted to sync but I encountered an error.

Answer (score 0):

Replace `implemantation()` with `implementation()`. The letter after `m` is `e`, not `a`.